# Populating an Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to populate a spinner with the result of a query, like this:

```
DataBaseHelper mDbH = new DataBaseHelper(this);
Spinner combo1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combo1);
mDbH.open();
Cursor c1 = null;
c1 = mDbH.consulta4();
startManagingCursor(c1);
if(c1.moveToFirst() == false){
  Log.e("cursor c ","vacio");
  c1.close();
  mDbH.close();
}else{
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c1,new String[] {"nombre"},new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  combo1.setAdapter(adapter);
  c1.close();
  mDbH.close();
}
```

But when I test my app, it doesn't work! LogCat doesn't show any errors! I'm kind of lost here!

Any ideas?

Comment: Try not to close the cursor. Remove  c1.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your cursor after passing it to the SimpleCursorAdapter.
By doing this, you make your Cursor release its data and make it unusable. Therefore, SimpleCursorAdapter cannot use it anymore.
Remove this line in the else part of your code (after setAdapter):

```
c1.close();
```

And try again.

Comment: But, I've read over the internet that cosing the cursor is a best programming practice! Plus, I'm closing it if the cursor is empty in the if condition, then I'm closing it after SimpleCursorAdapter uses it! So I don't see the logic in this... unless SimpleCursorAdapter closes the cursor at the end of its lifecycle and I'm double closing it, but this I don't know for sure...

Comment: You only close the cursor when you are finished consuming the data it contains. SimpleCursorAdapter will need the data as long as you need to display the Spinner elements. So, as long as the Spinner uses the Cursor (through SimpleCursorAdapter ), it must remain open.
I don't know if it will be closed automatically but if you want to close it, you should do it when finishing the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

`startManagingCursor(c1)` already handle the close for you. Here your adapter will need the cursor to render your objects on screen so you should not close it.